# increasing expressiveness in array elements test

Tags: python, readability, performance

I like Python for it's expressiveness. I can't express everything as compact as I'd like to, though. For example this one I write quite often:

```
  def is_everything_okay(some_array):
    for s in some_array:
      if not is_okay(s):
        return False
    return True
```

But that's more Java then Python. How to improve the expressiveness (and probably execution speed) of that code snippet?

Comment: Are you asking about `any()` and `all()`?

Comment: Is any better in the case of an early false result (which doesn't need the checks to continue? How to formulate it correctly?

Comment: You have `timeit` to confirm the performance.  If that's actually your question.

Comment: My question is about if you would like to write up a comprehensive answer to get my upvote and if better then Sven Marnach's also get my `accept`.

Comment: "My question is about "?? I still don't understand the question.  I can't write up a comprehensive answer.  Either it's simply about `any` and `all` or it's about the performance of `any` and `all`.  Since `timeit` is available, you could easily post the timing so we can then answer a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built-in function [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all):

```
all(is_okay(s) for s in some_array)
```

Comment: looks much more like what I want. is it also faster or does it do the same "under the hood"?

Comment: @erikb: Of course it does the same -- what else should it do?  It's slightly faster since it is written in C, but for this example, it still needs to call the Python function `is_okay()` for each `s`.

Comment: Doing the same in well written C is of course something different in terms of speed! Also it can be parallelised for faster results with multicore processors and/or order/index the array before the start if it helps anything. I have no idea!

Comment: It can't re-order the tests: the defined semantics are that it operates on the s's in order.

Comment: Also does it include the speedup from returning False right when the first False is found?

Comment: Yes, both all() and any() short-circuit.

Comment: @erikb: Don't expect too much speed-up because the function is written in C.  The test the must be executed in every iteration is still Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to fill it in Sven's answer*...
docs for 2.7 : http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all

> `all(iterable)`
>   Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).
>
> Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
> return True
> ```

Almost an exact copy of the code you show...

So, using a comprehension of the form `(is_okay(s) for s in some_array)` creates the iterable which is parsed by `all()`

Without specifically testing, you won't know which is faster.

- and because I'm trying to wrap up a Python class I'm taking and need to answer some questions!